# SEHException in CUDA with EmguCV

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I try to build project with CUDA in EmguCV (wrapper of OpenCV). I installed CUDA version 10.0, NuGet package Emgu.CV.runtime.windows version 4.3.0.3890, Emgu.CV.runtime.windows.cuda version 4.3.0.3890. When I test this with command `CudaInvoke.HasCuda`, it is true. When I do this everything works:

```
Net net = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromTensorflow(_modelFile, _configFile);
net.SetInput(DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(image.Mat, 1, new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300), default(MCvScalar), false, false));
Mat mat = net.Forward();
```

But when I add CUDA background and target:

```
Net net = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromTensorflow(_modelFile, _configFile);
net.SetPreferableBackend(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Backend.Cuda);
net.SetPreferableTarget(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Target.Cuda);                
net.SetInput(DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(image.Mat, 1, new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300), default(MCvScalar), false, false));                
Mat mat = net.Forward();
```

it doesn't work. It fails with "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException".

Exception appears in string `Mat mat = net.Forward();`

My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce 940MX (Maxwell 1.0).

May anyone help with this problem, please?

Comment: Since you installed both Emgu.CV.runtime.windows and Emgu.CV.runtime.windows.cuda, there could be an issue where visual studio is looking in two different places to run Emgucv. Have you tried uninstalling the windows package and keeping the cuda package?

Comment: Yes, I did it, but nothing works again, Now I opened Issue https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/343 and understood that problem was that I used OpenCV face-detector, but it is quantized model. Thats why I tried other model (res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel) but it doesnt work too :( 

May be you know which models I can use with Cuda for Face Detections that have accuracy not less than Single-Shot Detector (openCV face detector) model?

Comment: I know dlib's MMOD pretty good for processing on GPU, but MMOD has not too good accuracy for me (like Single-Shot Detector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found solution.
Firstly, you can't use quantized model (UINT8) with CUDA. You need to use [Caffe Model](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/dnn_samples_face_detector_20180205_fp16/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel) for this detector. You must choose necessary CUDA and cuDNN for your GPU. After that you can meet this problem again. But it is from your hardware. For a long time I couldn't understand what was wrong with me. But my code works successfully on other machines. So I think the problem is with my hardware. If you have encountered the same problem, do not hesitate to contact me.